# Getting value to dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `span` which is used to add some content to DB with the help of a popup box. My problem is that I don't know how to pass ID to dialog box.

HTML:

```
<span class="block"><span class="uid" style="display:none">1</span></span>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $(function() {
           $("#Relation").dialog({
                autoOpen: false
           });
           $(".addRelation").on("click", function() {
                var uid = $(this).find('span').html();                                     
                $("#Relation").dialog("open");
           });
      });
 });
```

This function opens a dialog box which used for adding datas.

```
 <div id="Relation" title="Add Relation">
      <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="userId" id="userId" value="userId" type="hidden" placeholder="Enter e-mail Id">
                <input class="form-control" name="rq_id" id="rq_id" value="rq_id" type="hidden">
                <input class="form-control" name="rltn_name" id="rltn_name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name">
                <input class="form-control" name="email_id" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter e-mail Id">
                <input class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Enter phone no">
                <input class="" name="newpic" id="newpic" type="file">
                <input type="radio" name="live_status" class="live_status" value="1">Alive&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" class="live_status" name="live_status" value="0">not Alive
                <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Now"/>
           </div>
      </form>
 </div>
```

When I click the `span`, the `span` data inside the dialog box. I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: where in the dialog you want the value

Comment: I have a hidden field rq_id. i need to print var uid in this input field.

Comment: Why do you have two document ready functions?

Comment: just set the value to the hidden field before opening the dialog.What is the issue in that?

Comment: @ShaunakD to be doubly sure that document is ready. :)

Comment: Do you want the content of `span` in `<input class="form-control" name="userId" id="userId" value="userId" type="hidden" placeholder="Enter e-mail Id">` ?

Answer (score 1):

Then add an hidden field like

```
<input class="form-control" name="uid" id="r_uid" value="111" type="hidden">
```

then set the value of the hidden field before opening it

```
$(function () {
    $("#Relation").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $(".addRelation").on("click", function () {
        var uid = $(this).find('span').html();
        $('#r_uid').val(uid)
        $("#Relation").dialog("open");

    });
});
```

Comment: @user2745897 _Johny_, not _Jhony_.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `span` value in `<input class="form-control" name="userId" id="userId" value="userId" type="hidden" placeholder="Enter e-mail Id">`, try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(function() {
           $("#Relation").dialog({
                autoOpen: false
           });
           $(".addRelation").on("click", function() {
                var uid = $(this).find('span.uid').html(); 
                $('#userId').val(uid);                               
                $("#Relation").dialog("open");
           });
      });
 });
```